# is possible to compute Class properties dinamically by received constructor arguments?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Basically I want to achieve is merging this two clasees:

#### class ResponseDto

```
export class ResponseDto<T = Record<string, any>>  {
    public readonly sucess = true;

    constructor(
        public data: T
    ) { }
}
```

#### class IterableResponseDto

```
export class IterableResponseDto<T = Record<string, any>[]> {
    public readonly sucess = true;

    constructor(
        public data: T,
        public paging: Paging
    ) { }
}
```

As you can see, when `data` argument is an Array you may provide a `paging` argument of certan type, otherwhise only `data` sall be mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to represent the [type of the rest argument tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) for the constructor:

```
export class ResponseDto<T extends Record<string, any> | Array<Record<string, any>>>  {
  public readonly sucess = true;
  public paging: Paging | undefined;

  constructor(
    public data: T,
    ...[paging]: (T extends Array<any> ? [Paging] : [])
  ) {
    this.paging = paging;
  }

}
```

Above, the `paging` argument will be accepted if and only if the type of `T` is an array.  Inside the class's implementation you have the `paging` property set to `Paging | undefined`.  It might turn out to be difficult to have the class implementation know when `Paging` is and is not present, since conditional types that depend on unspecified generics are hard for the compiler to reason about.

But at least from the caller's side it should work as expected:

```
declare const paging: Paging;

const okayObject = new ResponseDto({ a: "hello" });
const badObject = new ResponseDto({ a: "hello" }, paging); // error!
// expected 1 arg, got 2

const okayArray = new ResponseDto([1, 2, 3], paging);
const badarray = new ResponseDto([1, 2, 3]); // error!
// expected 2 args, got 1
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwOag8g3gKGWQAdMIAuZEAVwFsAjaAbnwF9l98IAPYgeyhhkCADZwAzuOQAlCOP4hxEACJg+AHgAqyHpBAATKbIQD968WCjYANMjggAngD5kAH2QBBKFDgP1x03NLGztHJ3CiAiJianoRYARkKAg4fT4QEQdkcWokSWQAXmRLaggWaNj4xNIsEAxKdFqcd2oDCBhQCH0WQmF0iyhctSgACl6KuITkfTgwOEpNa3HkADo1gG0a7ABdShHtXQgDKS8fP3tnZAB+ZHXGneRKde2ASl6XvGWwAAtgcRWtnVCiRMNhyshWJxIfh9BBRHBkn1FEJAfU0KC6j0TMjkHwANa+ADy9AAVnChEUQBAAO4yOQKJSqPgjXB2SgAIm+EBEIj47IhLxY2IsyHoqWJZIQFKoNLp8n6KjULLZyE53N5-NYtlRguQAHo9TpvAIAIT4A06XjkrrIACMdigGFsGD4QgATJxhUJ8b5Tr5gVTabJ5YpFcz1rbbG7bABmbbajEYQX4L2i1IIs4B2XBhlhkYRqOx15MfWG6BQU3mstWqU2t0OjDiZ2uu1AA)

Comment: capeless hero!

thanks this is excactly what I wanted